# How to bring application to foreground when SMS is received in Android

Tags: android

I have an application in android which receives SMS in a specific port. When my application is not running or it is running in background, how can i get the application to foreground and receive the SMS automatically?
Currently it is not receiving an SMS when it is in background. The SMS is only received by the native Messages application.

Also  I want to use sendOrderedBroadcast because my messages should not be stored in native message inbox. So, i have to use sendOrderedBroadcast. Does anyone have an example code for how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read this I think can help you...
http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-braodcast-receivers.html